# text does not want to be under the image. using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hi guys do you know how to make this text under the image. i've tried use absolute on the text and it's work but when i test the responsive text gonna be the bottom of content not under the picture.
#sorryforbadenglish

```css
.fitur {
  padding: 15px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.fitur .btn-get-started {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 28px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  color: #fff;
  background-image: url("../img/gplay.png");
  background-size: cover;
  width: 210px;
  height: 61px;
}

.fitur .col-half-offset {
  margin-left: 4.166666667%
}

.fitur p.sub {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.fitur img {
  max-width: 200%;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.fitur img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.15);
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .fitur img {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {}

@media (max-width: 500px) {}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="fitur" class="fitur section-bg">
  <div class="container" data-aos="zoom-in">

    <div class="section-title">
      <p style="margin-top: 100px;">Fitur</p>
      <h3>Aplikasi</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-2 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <img src="assets/img/aplikasi/01.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        <p class="sub">Jual Sampah</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-2 col-half-offset d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <img src="assets/img/aplikasi/02.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        <p class="sub">Harga Real Time</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-2 col-half-offset d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <img src="assets/img/aplikasi/05.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        <p class="sub">Transaksi Terdata</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-2 col-half-offset d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <img src="assets/img/aplikasi/06.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        <p class="sub">Layanan Komunikasi</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-2 col-half-offset d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <img src="assets/img/aplikasi/07.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        <p class="sub">Rangkuman Transaksi</p>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="d-flex">
      <a href="#" class="btn-get-started"></a>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

the result is :
[image]

The text is next to the image, can you help me how to take it under the image ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add flex-column to the parent div which contains the image and text. Like this

```
<div class="col-lg-2 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center flex-column">
    <img src="assets/img/aplikasi/01.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
    <p class="sub">Jual Sampah</p>
  </div>
```

By default the flex direction is row and it needs to be set to column so that the image and text are stacked on top of each other